# Select value from different row based on value of certain column

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example I have data like this like this

```
    date     |  col_1 |   Col_2 |   Col_3   | Col_4
---------------------------------------------
 20021   |   1    |   a     |   null    |   a
 20022   |   2    |   a     |   null    |   a
 20023   |   3    |   a     |   null    |   a
 20024   |   4    |   a     |   4.5     |   a
 20031   |   1    |   a     |   11      |   b
 20032   |   2    |   a     |   2       |   b
 20033   |   3    |   a     |   9       |   b
 20034   |   4    |   a     |   11      |   b
```

what I need is when value in Col_3 is null and Col_1 is not 4,
then select value in Col_3 where Col_1 = 4, that have the same

I tried using this case statement:

```
select col_2, date, col_1, col_4,
   case when col_3 is null and col_1 != 1
     then (select col_3 from table s where s.date = 4
           and s.col_1= seg.col_1 and s.col_4= seg.col_4
           and left(s.date,4) = left(seg.date,4))
    else seg.col_3
  end as col_3
from table seg
```

but for some reason it's not doing what I need it to do
I need it to change the results of the table above to become like this:

```
    date     |  col_1 |   Col_2 |   Col_3   | Col_4
---------------------------------------------
 20021   |   1    |   a     |   4.5    |   a
 20022   |   2    |   a     |   4.5    |   a
 20023   |   3    |   a     |   4.5    |   a
 20024   |   4    |   a     |   4.5     |   a
 20031   |   1    |   a     |   11      |   b
 20032   |   2    |   a     |   2       |   b
 20033   |   3    |   a     |   9       |   b
 20034   |   4    |   a     |   11      |   b
```

Comment: Edit the question add expected result too.

Comment: That sub-query seems to be a bit risky. It will probably return more than 1 row, which means an error is raised.

Comment: Can you please provide an output example, this will increase the chance to get a reply.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, I edited and added the expected results

Comment: @Shadizz You wanted to update the value Col3 from the record where Col1=4 .. all fine. But there are 2 records with Col1=4 for Date = 20024  & 20034 but you updated with only value 4.5 while there is another record with value 11. Requirement should be refined again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use an `OUTER APPLY` (or `CROSS APPLY` if you can guarantee quarter 4 is there) to always have quarter 4 available per year per col4 then just use it where you have to.

```
select col_2, date, col_1, col_4,
   case when col_3 is null and col_1 != 4
     then backfill.col_3
    else seg.col_3
  end as col_3
from table seg
outer apply (select col_3 from table where col_1 = 4 and left(date,4) = left(seg.date,4)) and col_4 = seg.col_4) backfill
```

If you'd rather stick with CASE, this should work.

```
case when col_3 is null and col_1 != 4
     then (select col_3 from table s where s.col_1 = 4 
           and s.col_4 = seg.col_4
           and left(s.date,4) = left(seg.date,4))
    else seg.col_3
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use window functions and `coalesce()`:

```
select date, col1, col2, 
       coalesce(max(case when col1 = 4 then col3 end) over (partition by col4) as col3,
       col4
from t;
```